# Loading partial html template into Angular app using Laravel

Tags: angularjs, rest, laravel, laravel-routing

I'm trying to use the RouteProvider functionality in Angular. A different partial html template should be loaded depending on whether the user is editing a form, viewing a list of completed entries, etc. I've been unable to load the html templates within the same page. Instead, the user is redirected to a different page.

Here's the relevant Angular code:

```
.when(/new', {
  controller: 'CreateCtrl'
  templateUrl: 'partials/newform.html'
```

The Laravel Route:

```
Route::resource('services', 'ServicesController');
```

The newform.html file is located at resources/views/partials/newform.html within Laravel.

Any thoughts on how I can load these partial html templates from Laravel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be to reference the full path to the partials

```
.when('/new', {
   controller: 'CreateCtrl'
   //depending on your path adjust it
   templateUrl: 'partials/newform'
```

since you are just using `.html` not `tempalte.blade.php` file for template you should move it to public folder.

**Update:**
If you really dont want to move the template out of view folder of laravel

create a route and serve your html from there

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'partials'), function(){

      Route::get('/newform', function()
      {
        return File::get(app_path().'Views/partials/angular.html');
      });
});
```

**Note:** I will suggest you not to mix Laravelc template with Angular, keep Laravel as REST API, and your Angular should separate layer.

[Here are some Pros and Cons for both approach](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/10/working-with-a-laravel-4-plus-angular-application/)

Comment: @Squeib Thank you for the suggestion. The user is no longer being forced to a new page, but the html isn't loading in the ng-view.

Comment: Check your console and make sure `newform.html` file is loading. serve your application using localhost

Comment: @Squeib it shows a 404 error. But the path looks correct. http://laravel.app/resources/views/partials/newform.html

Comment: so its not loading, where you kept the angular index.html file, is it in `public` folder

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not having much luck. That throws an error: `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Routing\Router::group() must be of the type array, string given, called in . . . facade.php`.

Comment: sorry, it was an syntax error in answer, now fixed check

Comment: I've updated my code, but am still getting a 404 error.

Comment: try visiting `http://laravel.app/partials/newform` in browser and see if template loads, I will say again move your html in `public` folder to make your life easier

Comment: the template loads when I visit through browser. will add to public folder as you suggest. Would I still need to set up a Laravel route for that?

Comment: no, if its in public folder, you don't. just make the `templateUrl: 'partials/newform'` path correct

Answer (score 1):

I found another way using gulp, i leave my solution :)

1. In gulpfile.js inside elixir function add this line:

```
 


     var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
        elixir(function(mix) {
            mix.copy('resources/assets/js/angular/components/**/*.template.html', public/angular-templates'); 
//Find all files with suffix .template.html
    });
```

As you notice it, i created a folder called 'angular' and then another one called 'components', there we will have our components

```
    Angular----------------------------- 
    --Components------------------------ 
    ----my-component.directive.js------- 
    ----my-component.template.html------
```

2. We have to create a global angular variable taking our browser window origin (www.myapp.com, localhost:8000, etc) by doing:

```
    angular.module('myModule',[])
    .value('pathAssets', location.origin + '/angular-templates/')
```

3. In our templateUrl we will call the template by writting:

```
    templateUrl: pathAssets + '../angular-templates/my-template.html',
```

I have to say we have to concat our angular files in a file, otherwise it won't work D: if you don't know how to do it, add these lines in your gulpfile.js

```
    mix.scripts([
        '../../../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js',
        'angular/app.js',
        'angular/controllers/**/*.controller.js',
        'angular/components/**/*.directive.js',
        'angular/bootstrap.js',
], 'public/js/app.js'); //We concatenate angular files saving them in app.js
```

4. Finally execute the command 'gulp' in terminal(In our project), it should generate a new folder in public called angular-templates.

CONCLUSION 
1. Move all your angular templates to public inside a specific folder by using elixir.
2. create a global variable in angular to save your origin URL and use it in your directives it automatically with this template in public.